# can not get ThreadLocal variable that is set in Session Listener from Filter

Tags: java

I would like to set a value to threadLocal when session is destroyed, and want to get it in Filter. But i can not get it, it shows null. how can i get it?

below is the code of Listener:

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public static ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MySessionListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent)
     */
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)  {

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent)
     */
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event)  {

        threadLocal.set("timeout");
        System.out.println(threadLocal.get());  //timeout
    }
}
```

the part of the code in Filter:

```
String flag = MySessionListener.threadLocal.get();

System.out.println(flag); //null

if (flag != null && flag.equals("timeout")) {
    MySessionListener.threadLocal.set("");
    dispatcher = this.request.getRequestDispatcher("/relogin");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
} else {
    dispatcher = this.request.getRequestDispatcher("/error");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why would the listener be executed by the same thread as the filter?

Comment: @JB Nizet I would like to check if the user has not logged in or the user has logged in but session is expired

Comment: At login, store the user ID in the session. If this ID is not in the session, then the user has not logged in yet, or has a new not-logged-in session because the logged-in one has expired. As simple as that. No need for listener or threadlocal.